# Why won't my macbook pro wake up when docked?

Tags: macbook-pro

I got a HengeDock for Christmas.  When I close my Macbook Pro and dock it to the external monitor, mouse, and keyboard, it will not wake up.  I move the mouse around and type on the keyboard, but it stays asleep.  Is this because I have a non-Apple monitor (I have a Sumsung -- highly rated by Consumer Reports).  Is something set incorrectly in my preferences?

Comment: What OS are you running? Your mouse & keyboard USB or bluetooth?

Comment: Is power supplied to the MacBook Pro through the dock? I know that mine will immediately sleep if disconnected from power while closed.

Comment: Mine will do the same thing if the power is not plugged in to my MacBook Pro. It will just go to sleep and not wake until power is plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's kbase article [HT3131](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131), your machine must be plugged into power for clamshell mode to work.